# Get last two bytes from a 64bit value

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am getting `0xABCDABCD.0.1` when I run the following code. I wanted to get the last two bytes `01b0` from val, but the output shows as `1`. I am masking the last two bytes using : `0x000000000000FFFF`

```
uint64_t val  = 0xabcdabcd010001b0;

int main() {


   printf("0x%X.%d.%x",(val&0xFFFFFFFF00000000)>>32, 
    (val&0x00000000FF000000)>>24,(val&0x000000000000FFFF));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compiling your code with gcc 6.3.0 I get `0xABCDABCD.1.1b0`. It works but the leading zeros on the second two values are dropped, use `%04x` if you need them.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings. `warning: format '%X' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 2 has type 'uint64_t' {aka 'long unsigned int'} [-Wformat=]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the results of the bitmasks are `uint64_t` types. To print correctly, you need this code, [online here](http://tpcg.io/POcCUU):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint64_t val  = 0xabcdabcd010001b0;

int main() {
   printf("0x%" PRIX64 ".%" PRId64 ".%" PRIx64,
    (val&0xFFFFFFFF00000000)>>32, 
    (val&0x00000000FF000000)>>24,
    (val&0x000000000000FFFF));
   return 0;
}
```

See the section "Format constants for the std::fprintf family of functions" on [this page for more formats](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty of rewriting the code for you, dropping the massive masks and adding the awful inttypes printf defines.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint64_t val  = 0xabcdabcd010001b0;

int main() {
    printf("0x%" PRIX64 ".%" PRIx64 ".%04" PRIx64 "\n",
        val >> 32, 
        (val >> 24) & 0xFF,
        val & 0xFFFF
    );  
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the only functional change is adding the leading zeros to the third print argument.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this polished version can be of use to you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
uint64_t val = 0xabcdabcd010001b0;

int main() {
   void *p1, *p2, *p3;
   p1 = (void *) (val & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000 >> 32);
   p2 = (void *) (val & 0x00000000FF000000 >> 24);
   p3 = (void *) (val & 0x000000000000FFFF);
   printf("%p.%p.%p\n",p1, p2, p3);
   return 0;
}
```

Trick that a pointer type can handle those ints as addresses in a x64 machine.

Comment: Note, `p2` should be printed in decimal according to the original code.

Answer (score 0):

`%X` and `%d` require `int` arguments, but you are passing `uint64_t`. Try using `PRIu64` and `PRIx64` macros instead. See [cpp.sh fiddle](http://cpp.sh/9zx72):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

// ...

   printf("0x%" PRIx64 ".%" PRIu64 ".%04" PRIx64 "",
          (val&0xFFFFFFFF00000000)>>32, 
          (val&0x00000000FF000000)>>24,
          (val&0x000000000000FFFF)
          );
```